# no Route matched with those values

Tags: kong

I'm new to Kong and I have a problem with version 1.1.0. please your help

Original Service:
http://vextusapi-vextus.1d35.starter-us-east-1.openshiftapps.com/api/values

```
returns: ["value1", "value2", "value3", "values4"]

When using Kong:
Service:
{
    "host": "vextusapi-vextus.1d35.starter-us-east-1.openshiftapps.com",
    "created_at": 1554865495,
    "connect_timeout": 60000,
    "id": "65335d6b-0a49-467f-8b12-5830dfa61a2f",
    "protocol": "http",
    "name": "api-affiliates",
    "read_timeout": 60000,
    "port": 80,
    "path": "/ api / values",
    "updated_at": 1554865495,
    "retries": 5,
    "write_timeout": 60000,
    "tags": null
}

Route

{
    "updated_at": 1554865717,
    "created_at": 1554865717,
    "strip_path": true,
    "snis": null,
    "hosts": null,
    "name": "route-affiliates",
    "methods": [
        "GET"
    ],
    "sources": null,
    "preserve_host": false,
    "regex_priority": 0,
    "service": null,
    "paths": [
        "/ api / values"
    ],
    "destinations": null,
    "id": "8a2fd125-d042-444b-b8f9-14002437795c",
    "protocols": [
        "http",
        "https"
    ],
    "tags": null
}

Always answer
{
    "message": "no Route matched with those values"
}
```

What is my mistake?

Thank you!!!!!

Comment: Can you post your solution or the fixes

Comment: the service, the route, and the host must match the call for Kong to redirect the managed resource. In my case, the value of Host was null.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add `Host=vextusapi-vextus.1d35.starter-us-east-1.openshiftapps.com` in request header